# Class vs instance initialization in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I am a bit puzzled why when initializing an instance of a class in Python, I cannot use class attributes. Here is the example:

```
class TestClass:
... shared_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
... def __init__(self):
...     self.length = len(shared_list)
```

Now

```
>>> TestClass.shared_list
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

So the list exists before any instance of the class appears, but

```
>>> tc = TestClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
NameError: global name 'shared_list' is not defined
```

Am I missing something simple?

**UPD:** Thanks to everyone for help and a prompt response. I've cleared up my confusion: class doesn't define a scope in Python.

Comment: You need `self.shared_list` or `TestClass.shared_list` if you want the scoped `shared_list`

Comment: @AChampion Thanks, putting TestClass.shared_list fixes it. Coming from C++ I still find it confusing, that *within* the class I need an explicit reference to the class. I thought if an attribute is not found in the instance, it will be searched for in the class, and not globally, no?

Comment: Unfortunately not, see scoping rules post above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `class` definition doesn't create a new scope for its methods, just a namespace for local variables. This is documented to some extent in [Class Definition Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax):

> When a class definition is entered, a new namespace is created, and
>   used as the local scope — thus, all assignments to local variables go
>   into this new namespace. In particular, function definitions bind the
>   name of the new function here.
>
> When a class definition is left normally (via the end), a *class object*
>   is created. This is basically a wrapper around the contents of the
>   namespace created by the class definition.

That's why you need to reference the class attribute as `TestClass.shared_list` or `self.shared_list` in its method.

Comment: Thanks, that was precisely my source of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs in your `__init__` function, which is called when you instantiate `TestClass`.

The `__init__` function uses the `shared_list` variable, but in reality this variable can only be used when tied to an instance or the base class itself. If you want to modify the shared variable, you will have to call it with the class name:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.length = len(TestClass.shared_list)
```

If you want to modify the variable only for that instance, you will have to declare it as an instance variable:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.not_shared_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    self.length = len(self.not_shared_list)
```

Comment: Note: `self.share_list` will reference the `TestClass.shared_list` and any changes to `self.share_list` will modify the class variable.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks--modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, - I've upvoted your answer, but I accepted a different one, since it happened to address exactly my source of confusion: class doesn't create a scope in Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the "environment" of the variable `shared_list`, here it's `self` or `TestClass`, python thinks it is a global variable - which is nor defined.

Use `self.shared_list` or `TestClass.shared_list` to reference it.